# Is the Spectrum of a compact operator real?

Tags: operator-theory, compact-operators

In [Functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space)
 it has written that the spectrum of a compact operator is real. Is it true or it is a misprint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standing assumption in this section is that the operator is self-adjoint. In this case the spectrum is indeed real (and compactness is not needed for that). If the operator is not self-adjoint, then this is no longer true. Any matrix with non-real eigenvalues gives you a counterexample.